# Geometry nodes - align rotation?

Tags: geometry-nodes

So I'm trying to distribute the cones on torus (1 cone per face). How do I fix the rotation? Why are the cones rotated like this? Look at the lines.
Blender 3.1.2

[image]

Comment: pls upload blend file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why are the cones rotated like this? Look at the lines...

My best guess on why the lines appear to be unparalleled is because when you use the **Align Euler to Vector** node with the `Pivot` set to `Auto`, Blender will try its best to guess and choose the best axis to match the rotation towards the inputted vector.
[image]

This will work just fine for most cases when you care about matching only one of the three local axes (X,Y,Z) of your object towards the direction of the inputted vector and not having to care about the rotation of the other two axes. Because of that, in your case, for the rotation to match properly, the `local Y-axis` will need to be manually rotated first before you can rotate the `local Z-axis` to the direction of the inputted vector.

To do this, you'll need to use 2 **Align Euler to Vector** node. One to match the direction of the `local Y-axis` of the cone instances towards the direction of the inputted vector (these vectors are the flipped normal vectors that point towards the center). This will allow the cone instances to align with the edges of every faces that they're being instanced on.
[image]

The second one will be used to rotate the `local Z-axis` of the cone instances towards the direction of the inputted normal vectors.
[image]

The `BEFORE` is with only one **Align Euler to Vector** node, the `AFTER` is with two **Align Euler to Vector** node.
[image]

Here's the node setup:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Got half of it working :) What is that "faceworward" node?

Comment: "Faceforward" vector math node is basically used in cases where you want to flip the vectors on all axes. In this case, it'd be the same as taking the normal vectors and multiplying them with [-1, -1, -1] using the "Multiply" vector math node.

Comment: thank you! everything is working fine now. Learned alot :)